# jquery unobtrusive validation to contain some logic

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I am using `jquery unobtrusive validation` I am little confused how to use it in one condition. I have a `input type=text` and `jquery datepicker` and i want to allow only dates that contains some logic in validation. for example, I need date selected must be valid only if its five days ago, i.e, for today selection it must be 24th May.

the used syntax in `jquery unobtrusive validation` is something like below,

```
  <input type="text" name="startdate" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required.">
```

how can I add some validation logic to cater to my requirement?

Comment: If you can only select one date, why does it need to be edited?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I dont get it what u are saying. I need date selection, and it allowed only if its five-days-ago date

Comment: Do you mean you can only select a date between 24th May and 28th May? (allow the user to only select 24th May seems a bit pointless)

Comment: man I just need to allow date that is five-days-earlier. I dont need range. sorry if u r little confused by my question

Comment: Then why does the user need to select anything? If it can only be 24th May, then you do not even need a form control. You could just add some text in the view saying the date is 24th May.

Comment: I think you mean it can only be 4 days earlier than current date **&** current date included. And nothing out of this range. Is it correct?

Comment: no  I dont have this exact requirement. I just simplify for the sake of understanding

Comment: @A.Wolff yes its correct it will help me

Comment: So why don't you use `minDate` *&* `maxDate` of jQuery UI plugin: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: @A.Wolff cant I add logic or customize `jquery obtrusive validation` for achieving what I initially asked

Comment: @Alex, You can use one of the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) conditional attributes or you can write your own validation attribute - refer [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2), but its not clear what you want to validate (having a datepicker that allows a user to select only one date is pointless)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok I opened the file for unobtrusive validation and it seems its for simple validation not so special it max only 100 lines of code then I dont get it why microsoft brag about it so much

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there any js validation that I can use to achive real world validations?

Comment: The only purpose of `jquery.validate.unobtrsive.js` is to parse the form html and read the `data-val-*` attributes and add the rules and messages to the `jquery validator`. Its `jquery.validate.js` that does all the work :)

Comment: And what _real world validations_ are you referring to?

Comment: can i customize `jquery.validate.js`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113215/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).